# Using the number of statements in a function as a constant for memory allocation

Tags: c++, testing, macros, constexpr, static-memory-allocation

I have a function which executes a bunch of tests. Whenever a new test is created, the function gets one or two more lines. And - the result is pushed back into an array. So it goes something like this (simplified):

```
void foo(int *results) {
    auto index { 0 };

    results[i++] = test_1(some, args, here);
    results[i++] = test_1(some, other_args, here);

    results[i++] = test_2(some, args, here);

    results[i++] = test_3(some, args, here);

    // etc. etc.
}

void bar() {
    auto results = new int/* magic */];
    foo(results);
}
```

I want to use the number of statements in this function to allocate space for the results (the line in `bar()`). I *cannot* use a dynamically-reallocated structure like an `std::vector` or a list etc. - since I am precluded from allocating any memory due to hardware restrictions.

Now, I could just manually count the lines - and this would work. But then whenever I add another test I would have to remember to update the magical constant.

Is there some way to do the counting with the result usable for the "magic" expression?

Note: Since I'm a scrupulous man with no dignity, I am willing to stoop to the use of macros.

Comment: `const int foo_start = __LINE__;`

Comment: @melpomene: 1. That would count lines rather than statements; 2. It would count emtpy lines.

Comment: Use a collection. This is C++ after all.

Comment: @user207421 "*I am precluded from allocating any memory due to hardware restrictions*"

Comment: @user207421: Also, I will likely use a collection, but it's not in a standard library and I didn't want to complicate things here.

Comment: What's wrong with `vector`? It a correct `reserve` call call results in a single memory allocation and more readable code.

Comment: Have all those functions the same signature?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of macro hackery:

```
#include <iostream>

#define ADD_TEST(X) do { results[i++] = (X); (void)__COUNTER__; } while (0)

const int foo_start = __COUNTER__;
void foo(int *results) {
    int i = 0;
    ADD_TEST(100);
    ADD_TEST(200);
    ADD_TEST(300);
}
const int foo_end = __COUNTER__;

int main() {
    int results[foo_end - foo_start - 1];
    foo(results);
    for (int i : results) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

It's slightly awful and `__COUNTER__` is a non-standard extension in GCC and other compilers, but hey, [it works](https://ideone.com/1YyqfA).

The advantage is that it doesn't use any fancy C++ features, so in principle it should be compatible with older compilers and even C.

Comment: Now we're talking.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't specified any language version, though, did tag it with constexpr, I've solved this making use of C++17. This without any dirty macros. Instead, I'm relying on CTAD (Constructor template argument deduction).

First of all, I've assumed your functions are constexpr. That way, everything can be done at compile-time. (In the resulting code, you don't even see memory being used for the array.

```
constexpr int test_1(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}

constexpr int test_2(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a * b * c;
}
```

This isn't strictly needed, however, it can move unneeded calculations to compile time. It also allows propagating `constexpr` upto the final variable. That way, you could guarantee that none of the calculations will happen at run-time.

```
static constexpr auto myArr = createFilledArray();
```

However, the most important part is CTAD. A new C++17 feature that allows deducing the template arguments of your class based on the values that are passed at the constructor.
Instead of first creating an array, I create the array directly with all the different values that you pass to it. Since you haven't provided any arguments in your example, I assume they are known at compile time, which is again required for the constexpr waterfall. However, more importantly, I assume the number of elements is known at compile time.

By constructing all arguments when calling the constructor of `std::array`, there is no need for specifying its template arguments (note also the auto as return type). This gets deduced as `std::array<int, 3>` for this example.

```
constexpr auto createFilledArray(){
    std::array a
        {
            test_1(1, 2, 3),
            test_1(4, 5, 6),
            test_2(7, 8, 9),
        };
    return a;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    return myArr.size(); // Returns 3
}
```

[Code at compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TXMFs_)

From what I'm aware, there is [a proposal for C++20](https://github.com/ldionne/wg21/blob/master/generated/p1004r1.pdf) that is intended to make `std::vector` constexpr. However, none of the compilers I've tested at compiler explorer support this. This will most likely allow you to write code based on `std::vector` and use that at compile time. In other words, the allocated memory that represents your data, will be part of your executable.

A quick attempt of what your code could look like can be found [here at compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jnyrT6). (However, it ain't compiling at this point)

Comment: I don't mind the reliance on C++17 (at least, not for a SE answer), but - you can definitely not assume the test functions are constexpr. And if everything could be done at compile-time I wouldn't need to allocate memory on the heap to begin with.

Comment: As loosely mentioned in the answer, you can remove the constexpr from those functions and the variable, that way the values get calculated at runtime (if compiler optimizations don't kick in)

Comment: +1. However, this is a bit fragile, since if I wanted to insert other statements between the `test_nn()` lines, it would be a little tricky to do.